# Lego Bag Identification?

Tags: set-identification

My son has this bag of unopened lego with no instructions. Bag has numbers 135149 and says 2011. Colours are mostly brown and white. There are eye pieces included both open and closed with eyelashes.

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE Numbers found on bags, most of the time, are meaningless unlike pictures. Please update your question to include picture (or two) of the bag you have. This would help us identify unique pieces to narrow down search results.

Comment: I count 20 sets that have both "Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Black Eye Closed with Eyelashes Pattern" <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138pb028> and "Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Black Eye with Pupil Pattern" <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98138pb007>. But there are other eyes you might have meant instead. Really, we do need some photos.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, should I open it up to help?

Comment: Hopefully you don't NEED to open it, but if you're going to anyway, it might make it easier to see some of the pieces. I can't seem to spot the eye pieces in either photo, for example, so I'm guessing which ones they are.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

According to BrickLink, only set [10692 Creative Bricks](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10692-1) has all of:

- [Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Black Eye Closed with Eyelashes Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138pb028)
- [Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Black Eye with Pupil Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138pb007)
- [White Fence 1 x 4 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3633&colorID=1)

Do those eyes look right?

Comment: Yes that’s it! Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Sarah! Please note that if you find answer satisfying, you can and should indicate this by accepting it, i.e. setting the green checkmark on the left side (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))